# Trouble plotting the log error with respect to square root of N+M

Tags: python, math

I am fairly new to Python and I am having trouble plotting the log error of my error array with respect to kappa (square root of N+M). Any help is massively appreciated, thanks.

```
F = np.array([np.power(z, 2).real]).T
M= 5 #number of corners you are adding the poles too
N = 7 #number of poles in each corner


sigma = 4 #has to be 4 or greater
error = []
for n in range(N):
     kappa = np.array([(n+M)**(1/2)])
     Poles = []
     Dist = []
     for j in range(ncorners):
         dist = []
     if angleCheck(polygon, j) < np.pi:
        dist = np.exp(-sigma*(np.sqrt(n+1)-np.sqrt(np.linspace(1,n+1,n+1))))
        #dist = np.exp(-sigma*(np.sqrt(n)-np.sqrt(np.linspace(1,n+1,n))))
        Dist.append(dist)
        for d in dist:
            Poles.append(new_pole(polygon,j,d,0,False))
    else:
        dist = np.exp(-sigma*(np.sqrt(3*(n+1))-np.sqrt(np.linspace(1,3*(n+1),3*(n+1)))))
        Dist.append(dist)
        for d in dist:
            Poles.append(new_pole(polygon,j,d,0,False))
A = AMatrix(Poles, z, z_star, M)
alpha = np.linalg.lstsq(A, F, rcond=None)[0]
err = max(abs(A*alpha - F)/max(abs(F)))
error.append(err[0,0])
plt.plot(np.log(error[n]), kappa)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a mathplotlib function without importing it. Try adding `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: That is there, I have just omitted it sorry

Comment: You're welcome, could you validate the answer please ?

Comment: that is not why it's not working, I just didn't include the libraries in the question.

Comment: oh I see sorry then

Comment: do you get an error message ?

Comment: and could you include all the libraries you use in your question ?